# What is the term for a function that returns lazily evaluated expression?

Tags: javascript, lazy-evaluation, theory

I have a basic question, the term is on the tip on my tongue.

Given that `1 + 1` expression is eagerly evaluated:

```
var bar = 1 + 1;
```

And then it's wrapped with a function in order to be lazily evaluated:

```
function getBar() {
  return 1 + 1;
}

var bar = getBar();
```

The only purpose of `getBar` is to return lazily evaluated expression, the reason why lazy evaluation is in use is irrelevant.

What is the term for `getBar` wrapper in this context?

Comment: [Thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk)?

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, it is. Used it just a day ago the last time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In functional programming, this is called ["thunk"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk).

Java calls the functional interface that takes no arguments and produces a value [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html).